# psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: Connection refused in Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

so I tried to connect my docker app (python-1) into another docker app (postgres). But it giving me this error:

```
psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: Connection refused
python-1            |   Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
python-1            |   TCP/IP connections on port 25432?
```

I've tried using `condition: service_healthy` but it doesn't work. In fact, I already make sure my database is running before `python-1` is trying to connect. But the problem seems not about the database hasn't turned on yet. I already use `0.0.0.0` or postgres container's IP using `postgres` on the host and it also doesn't work.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.6
    ports:
        - 25432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "PGPASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}", "pg_isready", "-U", "${DB_USERNAME}", "-d", "${DB_NAME}"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 80s  
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
  python:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        postgres:
          condition: service_healthy
    command: flask --app app init-db && flask --app app run -h 0.0.0.0 -p ${PORT}
    ports:
        - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    environment:
      DB_HOST: localhost
      DB_PORT: 25432
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a container, `localhost` means the container itself.

Different containers on a docker network can communicate using the service names as host names. Also, on the docker network, you use the unmapped port numbers.

So change your environment variables to

```
environment:
  DB_HOST: postgres
  DB_PORT: 5432
```

and you should be able to connect.

Comment: It still gives me the same error 
```
psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: Connection refused
python-1            |   Is the server running on host "postgres" (192.168.16.2) and accepting
python-1            |   TCP/IP connections on port 25432?
```

Comment: Solved. I port forward my port like this `15432:5432` the left one is for outside the container and the right one is for the container. So when I use `postgres` host I should use `5432` port. I missed that part. Thank you.